# How to manage a long running procedure call to Snowflake using .Net Library

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am planning to write a stored procedure that I expect to take a long time to run.  It seems that if I use the .Net library, it will internally make repeated HttpClient requests until it discovers that the procedure call is finished.

Rather than keeping the Command.Execute method holding on for a result, is there a way to kill the Command.Execute if it doesn’t finish quickly and then check back with Snowflake later to see if the procedure has finished?

If I drop the Command.Execute before it completes, will Cloud Snowflake continue to execute the procedure?  If that is the case, I could just program the procedure to write a flag to a table to indicate that it has completed and then I can periodically ping that table for the completed flag.

Is there a better way to go about this?  Am I overthinking it, because no procedure call should take more than a few seconds?  I am a total newbie to Snowflake and am just trying to gain a little understanding.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of Snowflake Python Connector API , where i can execute execute_async() method of cursor object ; this asynch call submits query/procedure execution for asynchronous call; I strongly believe there must be similar method for .Net too

Just check for Python Snowflake Connector
[1]: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#label-python-connector-asynchronous-query-examples

Comment: This python api looks like exactly what I want, but I am not having any luck finding a .Net equivalent.